# Tool to manage multiple scripts run simultaneously

Tags: cron, multiprocessing, scheduled-tasks, scheduling

We have multiple scripts to run simultaneously on server, in order to perform some tasks. These scripts are set to run on a frequency via crons.

Using crons for this purpose as so many drawbacks. Like using crons we are unable to track if previous command completed then run it again otherwise wait for its completion. Also we are unable to get the errors occurred during script running and its output. This approach increases CPU load also.

So I need a tool where we can set these scripts, which executes only if previous one is completed and track output of those scripts as well. Firstly I tried to use ActiveMQ for this but I think this tool not suitable for this purpose.

Can someone please suggest me a tool for this requirement?

Comment: "*Also we are unable to get the errors occurred during script running and its output.*" How did you manage that? Cron usually sends you an email with that information for each run.

Comment: @melpomene: Mails does not work here because every hour we are running multiple scripts, and it is hard to manage it in emails.